Как исправить ссылку на главную страницу сайта?
Интернет магазин на платформе ocStore 3.0.3.7 , но не могу понять как убрать эту непонятную портянку на основной ссылке /index.php?route=common/home . Уже всё перепробовал, начиная плагинами, настройками магазина, включения seo pro и ЧПУ. И заканчивая бесполезными советами ChatGPT по типу "Найди файл .htaccess.txt и переименуй его в .htaccess (без расширения)."
